# .NET 5 WebApi Swagger Executes throw 417 (iis)

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger, webapi

1. I deployed my API's to my local IIS
2. I try to test them using swagger and the requests all throw a 417
3. When I run in IIS Express I don't have that problem.

What could be going on here?

Thanks for any ideas.
-Ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I simply needed to change the name of the app pool to match my website. It started working fine after that.